# ¿Como hacer funcionar puppeteer en lambda?

Tags: aws, lambda

necesito hacer una funcion lambda en la cual convierta archivos html a pdf, he investigado en varios lados para hacerlo funcionar pero ninguna me ha funcionado hasta ahora.

lo que he intentado es:

1. Instalar chrome-aws-lambda y despues puppeteer-core directamente en
   el src de la lambda
2. Instalar chrome-aws-lambda en un layer
3. Instalar chrome-aws-lambda y correr el Json Install de puppeteer
   (Esto no funciona por el limite de espacio)

y todas me devuelven el mismo error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

en el blog de aws puedes encontrar una solucion utilizando dockers en lambdas https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/architecture/field-notes-scaling-browser-automation-with-puppeteer-on-aws-lambda-with-container-image-support/

tambien puedes aplicar la solucion presentada en oxylabs https://oxylabs.io/blog/puppeteer-on-aws-lambda la cual te disponibiliza un packete de instalación, pero te recomiendan subir las capacidades de memoria cpu y ram de tu lambda.